# Creating a game of Checkers

Tags: c#, button

I am creating this in regards to an issue I just ran in with. I am trying to create a primitive game of checkers using only buttons and so far I am just testing how to get the program to recognize selecting a button and moving the piece.

My Code:

```
    private void Checkers_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    string selectedChecker = "";
    string currentButton = "";
    int blankSpace = 0;

    int[] Board = new int[64];

    private void gameBoard()
    {
        foreach(var control in Controls)
        {
            var button = control as Button;

            if(button != null)
            {
                if(button.Name == currentButton)
                {
                    button.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("Red Checker.png");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Dead.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Dead.");
            }   
        }
    }

    private void attemptMove()
    {
        string substringChecker = null;
        substringChecker = selectedChecker.Substring(0,2);
        int selectedCheckerNumber = Convert.ToInt32(substringChecker);

        string substringButton = null;
        substringButton = currentButton.Substring(0,2);
        int currentButtonNumber = Convert.ToInt32(substringButton);

        if((selectedCheckerNumber + 3 == currentButtonNumber) || (selectedCheckerNumber + 4 == currentButtonNumber))
        {
            Board[currentButtonNumber] = Board[selectedCheckerNumber];
            Board[selectedCheckerNumber] = blankSpace;

            gameBoard();
        }
    }

    private void newGameToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int w = pictureBox1.Size.Width;
        int h = pictureBox1.Size.Height;
        int count = 8;
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(w, h, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        w /= count;
        h /= count;
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
            {
                Color c = (i + j) % 2 == 0 ? Color.Red : Color.Black;
                Brush br = new SolidBrush(c);
                g.FillRectangle(br, i * w, j * h, w, h);
                br.Dispose();
            }
        }
        g.Dispose();
        pictureBox1.Image = b;
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }

    private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Close form
        this.Close();
    }

    private void howToPlayToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("How to play a game of Checkers: Step 1 - Don't play.");
    }

    private void informationToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void checkerSpace18_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void checkerSpace17_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        string buttonClicked = btn.Name;

        if (selectedChecker == "")
        {
            selectedChecker = buttonClicked;
        }
        else
        {
            currentButton = buttonClicked;
            attemptMove();
        }
    }
}
```

My question goes with regards to my `attemptMove()` method. I run into a runtime error:

> "An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll. Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format."

It seems to occur whenever I go to move the piece to the other cell adjacent to the piece after moving it once. It may be because my program is not updating the pictures of the buttons when the buttons switch, but I wanted to see if any guidance could be shed upon this issue.

Comment: I took a look into it and I noticed that it kind of broke the code and said that I was missing an argument.

Comment: When you stepped through the code with the debugger did you find anything amiss? Did you examine the values being accessed and find they were all as expected?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the "selectedChecker" to the clicked button .Name property. Then you are using substring(0,2) to get the first 2 characters and try to convert that to an integer.

Since a Name property can't start with numbers, you are attempting to convert some random text to an integer property.

A better approach would be to use the Tag property to hold information about the number, this can be any value. You can then use the int.Parse to parse the Tag value of the button.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I must say, I do not fully comprehend the Tag property just yet, but I will try and give it a shot.

Comment: @Zanpo the Tag property is a place you can place anything you want, and it "travels" with the control. You can place simple text here or complex objects. Think of it like a tag on a garment, it contains information the maker of the garment intended to be used by somebody else. In the case of the control, you're the maker, and you can place anything in the tag you want for use later.

Answer (score 0):

What is your naming convention for the buttons? Seems like you're trying to get a number from the name, but the conversion is failing.

If the button names are `button00` through `button63`, then you should be able to get the number using `Substring`, starting at `Name.Length - 2`. Note that you must have all button names use a two digit number at the end (`00`, `01`, `02`, etc).

For example:

```
// Get the last two characters of the button name
string substringChecker = selectedChecker.Substring(selectedChecker.Length - 2);

// Convert the characters to an integer
int selectedCheckerNumber = Convert.ToInt32(substringChecker);
```

Comment: Using `int.TryParse` instead of `Convert.ToInt32` would allow for some error checking, but since you are in control of the button names, that shouldn't be necessary.